# Removing left margin on website

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to remove the left margin which goes down the side of my [site](http://dylanapp.weebly.com) but can't work out where in the CSS it is located. I am using Weebly however you can still change all of the CSS, I just can't find it. If you scale the page down to iPhone size, you will notice there is a margin on the left and nothing on the right. Can I make these equal?

CSS Code is available [here](http://txt.do/8w00) (too long to post here :P)

Thanks

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Im not seeing any margin when resized to mobile dimentions. does it only show on resized browser or on mobile devices?

Comment: Easiest and best place to start is the with web inspector. It'll make it easy to dig into the structure of the page and find the element that has the margin. As a bit of a stab in the dark, I'm also not seeing any obvious margin so a full code example or fiddle would be handy here at the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.splash-page .main-wrap {
  overflow:hidden; // Hide both scrollbars
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your heading:

```
<h2 style="text-align:center;" class="wsite-content-title">Weekly Flix</h2>
```

Has the following styles applied:

```
font-size: 100px !important;
```

This size font is causing the word 'weekly' to have a width of around 365px, which is acting like a min-width. If you reduce the font-size for mobile devices then your issue will be resolved. Something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    h2.wsite-content-title {
        font-size: 70px;
    }
}
```

Also, try not to use !important, as its a pain to overwrite

Comment: The problem is that the margin is applying to not just the title but all of the content. So I would presume this won't work for the rest of it all

Comment: As you say, the 20px margin is being applied to the heading, causing an effective mid-width of 405px, all your content responds to screen width, so it will fill the 405px. If you reduce your browser width down to 320px width, you are only seeing the left hand portion of your page because your content cannot fit in the viewport. Try my solution

Comment: Just gave it a go and am struggling to find where to put it in.